# how to fetch parent table same data when multiple foreign keys are present in child table pointing to same column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables named "users" and "userReviews". I want to fetch all the reviews of a specific user. but i don't know how my two foreign keys "reviewForUserId" and "reviewFromUserId" will give me the exact user's "fullName". i have attached photos of my tables

[image: user table with id and fullName]

[image: userReviews table and it's columns]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please, include in the question an example of the tables you are working on and also a [your attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at solving the issue, including eventually the full errors you encountered.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: What is your expected output, the full name of the reviewer or the reviewed or both?

Comment: The expected output was full name for both, it's done now, thank you everyone for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to join `users` twice. Once for `reviewforuserid` and once for `reviewfromuserid` from `userreviews`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM userreviews ur
            INNER JOIN users ufor
                       ON ufor.userid = ur.reviewforuserid
            INNER JOIN users ufro
                       ON ufro.userid = ur.reviewfromuserid;
```

And next time please don't post images. Use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements to show how your tables look like.